# How to create and mount file for read and write as a HFS+ filesystem in linux?

Tags: mount, dd, hfs+

I am trying to mount a file that will act as a read/write HFS+ filesystem. I am using arch linux based distro so I installed hfsprogs and hfsutils. In debian based distros hfsprogs should be enough.

I created a 8G file like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1024 count=0 seek=$[1000*8000]
```

Then I did the formatting:

```
mkfs.hfsplus -v TestImg test.img
```

After that when I try to mount the file I get:

```
mkdir /tmp/sun
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o loop,rw,offset=0 test.img /tmp/sun
mount: /tmp/sun: mount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Parted shows that offset it ok:

```
sudo parted -m test.img unit B print
1:0B:8191999999B:8192000000B:hfs+::;
```

I also tried to use fdisk with the file creating sun partition table but that did not help either. Can you help me please with creating HFS+ rw filesystem as a file?

Comment: What is `$[10*8]` please?

Comment: It is number if block sizes that I need to create. Here for example block size is bs=100M, which is 100 megabytes. I need a disk of 8 Gigabytes, that is 10 * 100 Mb blocks 8 times. Whatever is in square brackets is returned just as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used loop device inappropriately.
The correct steps are:
Create file

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=100MB count=10 seek=$[10*8]
```

Create blocked device mapped to that file:

```
losetup -fP test.img
```

At this point blocked device /dev/loop0 got created.
Create filesystem:

```
mkfs.hfsplus test.img
```

Mount to your folder

```
mount -o rw,loop /dev/loop0 /tmp/loop_test
```